# Excel Spreadsheet split numbers into cells and add value below the number if it was in the list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet similar to the below with 2K-3K lines. There is a list of results that I want to first split (based on `-` from column B) then sort them in a way based on the numbers the `Test*` is in.
So in the end I want the names of everyone in column A that selected 1, then the ones selected 2, etc. For example:

```
      A       |    B       |               
Row1 Test1    |  1-2-3-4-5 |
Row2 Test2    |  1-3-4-6-7 |
Row3 Test3    |  2-3-4-6   |
```

Create a new sheet and result should be

```
      A     |    B      |     C     |    D      |     E     |     F     |     G     |       
Row1  1     |    2      |     3     |    4      |     5     |     6     |     7     |
Row2 Test1  |   Test1   |   Test1   |   Test1   |   Test1   |   Test2   |   Test2   |
Row3 Test2  |   Test3   |   Test2   |   Test2   |           |   Test3   |           |
Row4        |           |   Test3   |   Test3   |           |           |           |
```

Column F has Test2 first then Test3 since these two contain value 6 in their list.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: what is your excel version?

Comment: Its `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098) 64-bit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula in A7:

```
=LET(TestNames,$A$1:$A$3,TestResults,$B$1:$B$3,
FILTER(TestNames,ISNUMBER(FIND(A$6,TestResults)),""))
```

Based on this sheet
[image]